# Accessing deeply nested items in json list object

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, for-loop, nested-lists

In Python3 I am performing a GET request to receive a very long JSON response with recurring Items.
The whole Response output is stored to a global variable, looking like this:

```
def get_users():
    url = "https://blablabla/api/users"
    headers = {"Authorization": accessToken, "Content-Type": "application/json", "Accept": "application/json"}
    r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    r_dict = r.json()
    return r_dict

get_user_function = get_users()
```

Response:

```
[
    {
        "created": "2021-01-1 09:02:35.112 +0000 UTC",
        "id": "123456",
        "clientID": "client_client",
        "name": "name_name",
        "old": true,
        "config": {
            "config_option_1": false,
            "config_option_2": true,
            "config_option_3": false,
            "config_option_4": false,
            "config_option_5": false,
            "config_option_6": false,
            "config_option_7": false,
            "config_option_8": "123",
            "config_option_9": "456",
            "config_option_10": "",
            "config_option_11": {},
            "config_option_12": {
                "config_option_12.1": {
                    "config_option_12.1.1": true,
                    "config_option_12.1.2": true,
                    "config_option_12.1.3": false,
                    "config_option_12.1.4": true,
                    "config_option_12.1.5": false,
                    "config_option_12.1.6": false,
                    "config_option_12.1.7": false,
                    "config_option_12.1.8": false
                }}}}]
```

This is about half of the first response Item, an the whole response object holds several thousand of these items.
Now I would like to create a dict and fill it with a couple of items from given list.

Any ideas or improvements on how to access deeper nested items like e. g. item["config"]["config_option_12"]["config_option_12.1"]["cofnig_option_12.1.1"]?

So far i have this:

```
my_dict = {item["name"]: [item["id"], item["created"], item["config"]["config_option_12"]] for item in get_user_function}
print(my_dict)
```

Here I'm struggling to access child items of "config". "Config_option_1 - 11" works perfectly fine, but "config_option_12" and further puts out KeyError: "config_option_12".

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have a json file.
This worked for me

```
import json 
 
with open('abc.json', 'r') as f:
    mydict = {'value': item['config']['config_option_12']['config_option_12.1']['config_option_12.1.1'] for item in json.load(f)}

print(mydict)
# result {'value': True}
```

Maybe try to store your r_json in some file and do what I did and try it again